# DAX Power BI circular dependence problem across multiple tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, circular-dependency

After years of benefitting from answers here, and long hours of research to resolve a DAX circular dependency, I'm posting my first question.   I am self trained, and hopefully, I'll explain properly.

For clarity, I'm giving full detail below, but **my basic question is how to avoid circular dependencies when calculating columns in one table that reference multiple other tables**.

I'm looking to build a report that shows total sales by salesperson from two tables, CRM_Opportunities and BMC_Usage.  Identifying the salesperson for each row of BMC_Usage involves referencing data from four other tables, which works fine within BMC_Usage, but results in a circular dependency when I try to link to the CRM_Users.

[relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5vvv.png)

I have five tables from three systems:

- Three tables from our CRM:    CRM_Users, CRM_Accounts and CRM_Opportunities.
- CRM_Users contains the `fullname` and `crm user_id` of each
  salesperson.
  CRM Opportunities contains rows of opportunities, each
  with `createdon` date, `client_id` and `salesperson_key`.
  CRM_Accounts contains `client_id` and `salesperson_key`.
- BMC_Usage contains sales data for our new product, but no sales person information.  Each row equates to one unique billable event.  It does contain the date when the service began, `start_date` and the client id field `bmc_client_id`.
- One table from our billing system, UBS_Accounts, includes the name of the sales person, `ubs_salesperson` along with the client id  `ubs_client_id`.

In order to produce a consolidated report by sales person, I need to first identify who the correct sales person is for each row of usage in BMC_Usage using the following series of calculated columns in BMC Usage:

First, find out who opened the last sales opportunity in CRM_Opportunity prior to start_date in BMC_Usage:

```
Last Opportunity Date = CALCULATE(MAX(CRM_Opportunities[createdon]),CRM_Opportunities[createdon]<=EARLIER(BMC_Usage[start_date]),CRM_Opportunities[client_id]=EARLIER(BMC_Usage[bmc_client_id]))
```

Next, in case there's been no opportunities created yet, check when the account was last created in CRM_Account and also prior to start_date in BMC_Usage:

```
Last Acct Date = DATEVALUE(CALCULATE(MAX(CRM_Accounts[account_createdon]),CRM_Accounts[account_createdon]<=EARLIER(BMC_Usage[start_date]),CRM_Accounts[crm_client_id]=EARLIER(BMC_Usage[bmc_client_id])))
```

Third, grab the `salesperson_key` field based on the Last Opportunity Date, or if blank, from the Last Acct Date:

```
salesperson id = IF(ISBLANK(BMC_Usage[Last Opportunity Date]),
    IF(ISBLANK(BMC_Usage[Last Acct Date]),
        BLANK(),
        LOOKUPVALUE(CRM_Accounts[salesperson_key],CRM_Accounts[crm_client_id],BMC_Usage[bmc_client_id],CRM_Accounts[account_createdon],BMC_Usage[Last Acct Date])),
    LOOKUPVALUE(CRM_Opportunities[salesperson_key], CRM_Opportunities[client_id],BMC_Usage[bmc_client_id],CRM_Opportunities[createdon],BMC_Usage[Last Opportunity Date]))
```

Now that I have the salesperson id, I can get the `fullname` from CRM_Users:

```
CRM salesperson = LOOKUPVALUE('CRM_Users'[fullname],'CRM_Users'[crm_user_id],BMC_Usage[salesperson id])
```

Since it's possible our CRM has no record for this client, I can also pull the `ubs_saleperson` name from our billing system, UBS_Accounts, although it is a less reliable source.

```
UBS salesperson = RELATED(UBS_Accounts[ubs_salesperson])
```

Finally, I arrive at who the salesperson is for each row of BMC_Usage by preferring the CRM name over the UBS_Accounts name:

```
calc salesperson = IF(ISBLANK(BMC_Usage[CRM salesperson]),BMC_Usage[UBS salesperson],BMC_Usage[CRM salesperson])
```

And it all works fine!

[calc salesperson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPUIH.png)

The problem is, I can't build a relationship between BMC_Usage and CRM_Users so that I can make a consolidated report.

[circular dependancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPsOy.png)

From reading online, I believe the problem is caused by the multiple calculated columns and possibly the presence of blank rows.  I've tried filtering options using ALLEXCEPT, DISTINCT and others but I can't seem to get it right.  I'm not sure if I should be filtering the local table or the tables I'm pulling information from, and I'm just lost.

If you've read this far....THANK YOU! I know it's a long question.  Perhaps you have an idea?

Comment: Why are you getting 3 columns with the same names (or blanks in some cases)? Wouldnt it make more sense to make one column with the first/preferred salesperson? This is probably even possible without relationships between the tables (I do this too for calls in a contact center where agents are connected to calls :)) -- By the way, it is a great question, this is how it is expected on SO, only thing that could be improved is add sample data to others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Max, thanks for your reply.  I can make try making it one column and see if that helps.  I was concerned one long combined formula would make my question even less readable.
Also, I think I can streamline this question.  I'm having the same problem, even when just working between the BMC_Usage table and the CRM tables, so no need to bring the billing system table into it.   So I'm going to resubmit and thanks for the tip on including sample data.